# copy cell values of named range in one sheet to same cell address of another named range in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

Is it possible to copy the values of a named range in one sheet and paste them in the same cell location of another sheet?

For example, I have named range `"old_desk_1"` in `sheet1!A24:A25` and named range `"desk_1"` in `sheet2!A24:A25`. Is it possible to copy the values in the cells of `old_desk_1` to `desk_1` without just doing the standard copy/paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, first I suggest looking at the following documentations.

- [Google Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Google Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Google Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Google Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

The above links will tell you about all the methods available for all the classes you will need to do this. Here is a basic example of what you're hoping to acheive.

```
function copyCells(){
   var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var theRange = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("YOUR RANGE");

   var destinationSheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("SHEET TO COPY TO");
   var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRangeByName("YOUR OTHER RANGE");

   theRange.copyTo(destinationRange);
}
```